# Python scripting for coins slot raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Hi guys just need a little help

```
old 5 php coin = 1 pulse (+1)
new 5 php coin = 3 pulse (+1)
old 10 php coin = 5 pulse (+2)
new 10 php coin = 5 pulse (+2)
```

What i want to happen is every time i will insert a coin to the coin slot machine eg. 10 php so the counter value would be 5 and then for me to get the value 2 i used this calculation result = value + counter / counter + 1 now my total variable value is 2 but when i insert 10 php + 5 php counter value is 6 and my if statements only accept counter pulse of 1,3,5 can you help me how i will reset the counter value and add to the result every time i insert a coin eg. 10 php 5 pulse value of total = 2 and insert again 5 php 1 pulse add +1 to the total so it will be total = 3.

by the way pin 16 reads the coin slot machine pulse and 12 is for button when i am done inserting a coin the total value will be printed.

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

counter = 0
total = 0
value = 0
vendoState = True

while vendoState:
    if GPIO.input(16) == 0:
        counter+=1
        sleep(.1)

        print counter

    if GPIO.input(12) == 0:
        vendoState = False

        counterHold = counter

        if counterHold == 1 or counterHold == 3:
            value = value + counter / counter
        if counterHold == 5:
            value = value + counter / counter + 1

        total = total + value
        counter = 0

        if total != 0:
            print total

        total = 0
        value = 0

    vendoState = True
```

Comment: Hi, stackoverflow is not a "please finish my task" kind of site. Do you have an actual question? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How can i reset the value of my counter back to zero every time i insert a coin and store the value of total every time i insert new coin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you trying to write whole program in one infinite loop just like arduino. For running this perfectly you have to use two infinite loops.

```
while True:
  while vendoState:
    if GPIO.input(16) == 0:
       counter+=1
       sleep(.1)

       print counter

    if counterHold in [1,3,5] or GPIO.input(12) == 0:
       vendoState = False

  counterHold = counter

  if counterHold == 1 or counterHold == 3:
    value = value + counter / counter
  if counterHold == 5:
    value = value + counter / counter + 1

  total = total + value
  counter = 0

  if total != 0:
    print total

  total = 0
  value = 0
```

Comment: But still get the same problem if i insert to different coins how can i make my code compute the pulse every coin is inserted.

Comment: Just check the first infinte loop as counterHold is not 1,3,5 then dont break the loop.``

Comment: Where i will define counterHold?

Comment: Use your above code by just replacing from the line while vendostate == True: with my suggested code.

Comment: it prints the coin pulse when i insert it but produce no output when i pressed button 12.

Comment: Actually what will button 12 expected to do.

Comment: How can compute the coin every time i insert coin? And when i press the button it gives me the computed result.

Comment: Just add if statement for Button 12 after print counter in the first loop

Answer (score 0):

Latest code

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

counter = 0
counterHold = 0
value = 0
total = 0
vendoState = True;

while True:
  while vendoState:
    if GPIO.input(16) == 0:
       counter+=1
       sleep(.1)

       print counter
       counterHold = counter
    if counterHold in [1,3,5] and GPIO.input(12) == 0:
        vendoState = False

  if counterHold == 1 or counterHold == 3:
    value = value + counterHold / counterHod
  if counterHold == 5:
    value = value + counterHold / counterHold + 1

  total = total + value
  counter = 0

  if total != 0:
    print total

  total = 0
  value = 0
```

when insert 2 coins 1 10 php = 5 pulse + 5 php = 1 pulse = 6 pulse no output when i press button 12